"ps: unknown option -- o" error when starting an Apache Spark HTTP server
When I run an Apache Spark server from the Git Bash command line of my Windows 10 (v. 22H2) laptop (x64), using the following command:
spark-submit Documents/Python/Temp/rumbledb-1.21.0-for-spark-3.5.jar serve -p 9090

The following error message displays:
ps: unknown option -- o

However, the server seems to run OK.
Why is this error message displayed? Should I be concerned? What can I do to solve the underlying issue the causes this error message, so that the message won't appear the next time I start Apache Spark?
